# how to get the column name resulting True in Pandas boolean reduction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
     0               1              2          A
-0.740485792    -0.299824912    0.169113705    1
 1.120120949    -0.62580736     0.013757667    2
-0.685112999     0.439492717    -0.484524907   3
```

I am trying get the column name which has all the values greater than 0,

I tried `(df > 0).all()`

```
Out[47]: 
 0    False
 1    False
 2    False
 A     True
 dtype: bool
```

How to get only the column name which are True,

My expected output is "A", thanks in advance.

Question 2 on sort_index()

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[3,2,1]}, index=[2,1,0])

 Out[395]:
    A
2   3
1   2
0   1

df2.sort_index(axis=1)

    A
2   3
1   2
0   1
```

expected output is,

```
    A
0   3
1   2
2   1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.columns`:

```
c = df.columns[(df > 0).all()]
print (c)
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: why `np.nan== np.nan` is False

Comment: is it possible to sort the indexes and not the values in a dataframe. When I am doing `sort_index()` it changes the value order too in the column. I dont want to change the values but only the indexes

Comment: It  is because it is by design. And for second question need `sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: I tried, `sort_index(axis=1)`
 but there is no change in my df

Comment: You need `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` - assign output back.

Comment: I tried in jupyter notebook , it displayed the output but there is no change in index order

Comment: It is weird, I have no idea. Can you show my your code?

Comment: You need `df2 = df2.sort_index(axis=0)`

Comment: Values also changing, please see my expected output, pls you try once

Comment: You are right, you need `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: What happens when `drop=True` what is actually dropping. Pls explain

Comment: @pyd - sure, it reset index to default values and not create new column of original index but delete it.

Comment: @jezrael can you explain how `df.quantile()` works. I read the documentation, but I need some more clarification